# C# .NET Visual Studio 2022 Project Missing References after pushing to remote repo

Tags: c#

I am encountering an issue with my solution that comprises multiple projects. While I can successfully build the solution without any problems on my local computer, my colleagues face missing references when they pull my changes from our repository.

As a result, they need to reinstall all the references to ensure the project builds correctly. Unfortunately, this introduces new changes to our source code, leading to additional commits and unnecessary noise in our repository.

Here is a visual representation of the missing references error:

[image: Missing references]

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are the references setup? posting excerpts from the .csproj files will help.

Comment: Also, your image link does not work.